# How to add date from the inputbox to populate the whole column in chosen Access table by the use of VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to know how to add date (dd.mm.yyyy) with the use of inputbox to populate the whole column in chosen Access table by the use of VBA.
As here:

Inserted 12.07.2018 into the Inputbox

```
BNAME|CH_DATE
sdjfj|12.07.2018
sdjdf|12.07.2018
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim sDate as String
sDate = InputBox("What is the date?")
Rem Here add code to make sure sDate is in expected format "dd.mm.yyyy"
DoCmd.RunSql "UPDATE [MyTableName] SET CH_DATE=#" & Mid(sDate,4,2) & "/" & Left(sDate,2) & "/" Right(sDate,4) & "#"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim vbSql as string
vbSql = "UPDATE tbl SET column=#" & Format(textBox1.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "#;"
DoCmd.RunSql vbSql
```

stick this in the appropriate event. Obviously rename tbl, column and textbox1 to what objects youre actually using.

edit for Erik

Comment: unfortunately it gives me textbox1 as invalid qualifier :( How would this work if I wanted inputbox instead of textbox, please?

Comment: #dd.mm.yyyy# is not a valid date format in JET SQL. #01.02.2011# will get interpreted as the 2nd of January 2011, not the first of February...

Comment: Well, i guess youre right. To store that format in the table it would need to be text.

Comment: Storing a date as text is all kinds of wrong. Always use the proper variable type to store information. Formatting is a consideration for output of data; it should never be a consideration for data storage.

Comment: i was only commenting that for the OP - if he actually needs it stored in that fashion thats how. I never said anything about condoning that behavior.

Comment: So no straightfoward answer I assume :)